# Links are unclickable at the footer bottom

Tags: html, wordpress, footer

I created a landing page with Wordpress and I inserted this basic HTML code at the bottom of it :

```
<p> שיווק דיגיטלי <a href="http://createak.co.il" target="_blank">createak</a> כל הזכויות שמורות</p>
```

I apologize for the foreign language. :-)
I have always used this code, but for some reason now it's unclickable on this specific landing page: http://mickeyberkowitz.com/.
I have no idea why it's happening, any suggestions?

Comment: i checked your website and the link is working. Are you sure, you have that issue ?

Comment: Elementor is covering the link with some kind of inner spacer (I'm inspecting it on mbp in chrome). So it looks like the page builder is the one to blame ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a CSS rule is making the container element for the final section (footer?) fixed, since there is no rule to hide the `overflow-y` the images show up fine however, the link is actually behind those images.

The CSS rule below fixes the container to `100vh` however the content inside the container is much "taller" and so that overflows down. Your link is positioned directly under the parent element of the container and because the height of the offending container is fixed, it doesn't move down.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

If you changed that CSS rule to the one below you'll see an improvement:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

You will then notice the large space between the bottom of the "trophy" image and button - this appears to be a "spacer" element probably created by a page-builder plugin. I'd remove this if I were you. In fact, there appears to be another spacer below that as well, these create blank space that you may want to remove - depending on the desired aesthetics of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I checked in your site. This is because, in your code other divs and elements are show over `<div id="footer-bottom">`

You need to add following code in CSS

```
#footer-bottom{
    z-index:9999;
    position:relative
}
```

*This is a quick Fix.*

But this may make other things non-clickable. So you need to adjust all your html divs and code properly with CSS.
Please use google chrome or firefox developers tool or inspect your code and fix divs that are overlapping each other.